# Is this modified implementation of binary search still O(log n)?

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-search

The following is a slightly modified implementation of binary search that finds the first occurrence of an Integer key.

**Is this still O(log n)?** I'm having some trouble determining whether this becomes O(n) in the worst case.

```
private static Integer lowestRank(Integer[] a, Integer key) {
    Integer lo = 0;
    Integer hi = a.length - 1;

    while (lo <= hi) {
        Integer mid = lo + ((hi - lo) / 2);
        if (key.compareTo(a[mid]) > 0) {
            lo = mid + 1;
        } else if (key.compareTo(a[mid]) < 0) {
            hi = mid - 1;

        // Modified here to return the first occurrence of the key, if it exists
        } else if (lo < mid) {
            hi = mid;

        } else {
            return mid;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: In what way is it modified?

Comment: My apologies, I've been looking at it for so long that I forgot it wasn't obvious. The third if block (lo < mid).

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I believe the 3rd conditional statement is the addition.

Comment: What is the purpose of that 3rd conditional?

Comment: To find the first occurrence of the key as stated in the description

Comment: @AlbertOrlando - Yes, you are right.  I read too fast :/

Comment: First step: profile it with test-data of different sizes to get an educated guess about the complexity

Comment: Not the best way to do that job.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46795712/binary-search-for-first-occurrence-of-k/46796136#46796136

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is still `O(log(n))`. The third conditional statement only runs if `key.compareTo(a[mid]) == 0` (because the previous two conditionals eliminate the inequality cases) and if `lo < mid`.

If the key exists exactly once in the array, this branch will happen at most once; if the key does not exist, it will not happen at all. Since the conditional itself as well as everything in the body of the conditional is a constant time operation, the running time remains `O(log(n))`.

What if the key occurs multiple times? First, what's the purpose of this conditional branch anyways:

```
else if (lo < mid) {
    hi = mid;
}
```

If `lo < mid`, it means we haven't scanned the full range of the list. Thus, we set `hi = mid`, thereby establishing `mid` as the upper bound for our search.

Thus, even if the key occurs multiple times, the search range is halved at every iteration.

Comment: That branch can occur more than once.  Consider `a = { 5, 5, 5, 5, ... }`, `key = 5`.

Comment: Yes, in that case, doesn't this become linear?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we model individual statements as *O(1)*, then our overall complexity is dictated by the number of loop iterations.

The number of iterations can only be *O(n)* if we're reducing the range (`[lo, hi)`) by a constant amount per iteration (on average).  In all three relevant cases, it should be evident that that's not the case - the range is always halving, on average.