# Why is there still an error case in this binary search of sorted array scenario?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, binary-search

For the record, I came across this question on some web coding site, but I am really interested in what I missed rather than scores. Here it goes:

Implement function countNumbers that accepts a sorted array of unique integers and counts the number of array elements that are less than the parameter lessThan.

For example, `SortedSearch.countNumbers(new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 7 }, 4)` should return `2` because there are two array elements less than `4`.

I give the following solution, however, I just can not figure out in what scenario will it fail? (the site says it fails 1 out of 4 tests). And I also am not sure what kind of assumption I can have for value `lessThan`.

```
public class SortedSearch {
    public static int countNumbers(int[] sortedArray, int lessThan) {

        if (sortedArray == null || sortedArray.length == 0)
            return 0;

        if (sortedArray.length == 1) {
            return sortedArray[0] < lessThan? 1:0;
        }

        int left = 0;
        int right = sortedArray.length-1;
        int middle = 0;

        while(left<right) {
            middle = left + (right-left)/2;
            if (sortedArray[middle]<lessThan) {
                left = middle+1;
            } else if (sortedArray[middle]>lessThan) {
                right = middle-1;
            } else {
                return middle;
            }        
        }
        return left;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(SortedSearch.countNumbers(new int[] { 1, 3, 5 }, 4));
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `System.out.println(SortedSearch.countNumbers(new int[] { 1, 3 }, 4));`

Comment: The fun in such challenges is to write your own tests. This is perfect to do some work with junit. Simply think about relevant cases, such: odd number of entries, even number, corner cases where the result should be 0 or 1. Just saying: if this about learning, then use it as opportunity to learn testing.

Comment: Also is there a better way to write it (in terms of index or else) so that i can write fewer 'if's on corner cases?

Comment: @user1559625 We have answered to your question. Can you please considering commenting whether the answer helped you or not, and accept the answer that answers your question the best?

Comment: @vivek_23 sure, i just marked the helpful answer, but has not accepted one 'cause i still have some doubt on the correctness.

Comment: @user1559625 ok, fair enough. I recommended a small change to your code. Did it work or did it not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make only `1` change.

> while(left < right)

to

> while(left <= right)

Answer (score 2):

Your code is currently doing *classic binary search*. You need to **modify** that to include your cases.

**For ex.** 
try your code with below test cases:

```
{ 1, 3, 5 }, 4) -> should output 2
{ 1, 3, 5 }, 2) -> should output 1
{ 1, 3, 5 }, 3) -> should output 1
{ 1, 3, 5 }, 6) -> should output 3
{ 1, 3, 5 }, 0) -> should output 0
```

most of these are failing with existing code.

Our goal is to find out the point where `middle` *is less than* given number and `middle + 1` *is greater than* it. Of course we can do this using binary search (modified).

I modified your code for classic binary search to include these cases (and comments added in the code):

```
while (left <= right) {
    middle = left + (right - left) / 2;
    if (sortedArray[middle] < lessThan && (middle + 1) < sortedArray.length
            && sortedArray[middle + 1] > lessThan) {
        // we have the point where middle is less and middle+1 is greater than given num
        return middle + 1;
    } else if (sortedArray[middle] == lessThan) {
        // we have found the number itself
        return middle;
    } else if (sortedArray[middle] < lessThan) {
        // recur in right part
        left = middle + 1;
    } else if (sortedArray[middle] > lessThan) {
        // recur in left part
        right = middle - 1;
    }
}

// given number is either lesser/bigger than all elements in the array
return lessThan < sortedArray[0] ? 0 : sortedArray.length;
```

Comment: how is last line handle 'bigger than all elements in the array' if it compares only lessThan with sortedArray[0]?

Comment: @user1559625 if the code execution goes till the last line, then its clear that would could not find any `middle` point we wanted. So there are only two cases left, given number is less that all elements or given number is greater than all elements.

Comment: thanks, and also why do we need '&& (middle + 1) < sortedArray.length' in the code?

Comment: @user1559625 to avoid array out of bound exception in condition -> `sortedArray[middle + 1] > lessThan`

Comment: with {1, 3, 5, 7} 4, initially left=0, right=3, finally left=right=middle=2, and we do not have '// we have the point where middle is less and middle+1 is greater than given num'. in other words, using binary search we can not guarantee that at the end middle<target, it could happen that middle>target

Answer (score 1):

Binary searches like yours are one of my pet peeves.  I wrote about what I think is the best way to usually write one over here:  [How can I simplify this working Binary Search code in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39416560/how-can-i-simplify-this-working-binary-search-code-in-c/39417165#39417165)

This is particularly well suited to your case.  Since you are trying to find a position instead of an element, you can simplify your code and make it faster by having only one comparison per iteration like this:

```
public static int countNumbers(int[] sortedArray, int lessThan) {
    int start = 0, limit = sortedArray.length;
    while(start < limit) {
        int test = start + ((limit-start)>>1);
        if (sortedArray[test] < lessThan) {
            start = test+1;
        } else {
            limit = test;
        }
    }
    return start;
}
```

Note that there are no special cases to take care of, and this will also work if the array contains repeated elements.