# Find index in string array where strings change from "good" to "bad" - interview question

Tags: arrays, algorithm, performance, binary-search

You are given a string array named `strs` with length `n`, when each string can have the value `"good"` or `"bad"`. It is also known that exists index `i` so that:
`0<=i<=n-1`, `strs[0]=strs[1]=...=strs[i-1]="good"`, `strs[i]=strs[i+1]=...=strs[n-1]="bad"`.
Pay attention that if `i=0`, it means that `strs` has only strings with the value `"bad"`.

Write an algorithm to find index `i`.
Desired run time: `O(logn)`

My attempt:
I'm sure you need to use binary search here, but for some reason I have a problem with the check of the middle element.
I thought of checking if the middle element has a value of `"good"` and the middle+1 element has a value of `"bad"`, but this can give out of bounce error.

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Nope, it can't give an out-of-bounds error because the problem specifies that `i` exists and is in the range `0<=i<=n-1`.

Comment: You don't need to check 2 elements regardless whether n is odd or even.  At each step, you just need to divide the remaining elements in half  (or half and half-1).

Comment: @stark, so how do you check for the wanted index in the algorithm? how can you know when it switches from "good" to "bad" without checking 2 elements?

Comment: @user3386109, it can get out of bounce in the way I chose to implement it, since in binary search you can get to a situation when left index is equal to right index. That will give out of bounce in my case since I check for two indexes in the array.

Comment: In the question, it is stated that *"the middle element has a value of `"good"`"*. If that's the case, then `middle+1` cannot be out of bounds. The problem description guarantees that there is at least one `"bad"` element in the array.

Comment: So the answer is to implement a binary search that ends with `left_index == right_index == middle == index_of_the_first_bad`. That way, as @stark pointed out, you don't need to check `middle+1`. You just need to run the binary search until the indexes are equal.

Comment: @user3386109, I don't understand your suggestion (specifically how you find "index_of_the_first_bad"). Can you write the algorithm as pseudo code?

Comment: Don't think in terms of finding the dividing line.  Just think in terms of looking for i.  That means check middle and eliminate half the numbers at each step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this answer over here, I explain that when you write a binary search, it's usually better to do a real binary search (making real binary decisions) to find the index where the element you're searching for belongs, and then check to see if it's actually there:

[How can I simplify this working Binary Search code in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39416560/how-can-i-simplify-this-working-binary-search-code-in-c/39417165#39417165)

In your case, the index is your desired result, so you don't even need to check:

```
int findIndex(string[] array)
{
    int minpos=0;  //smallest possible answer (array is all bad)
    int limit=array.length; //largest possible answer (array is all good)

    while(minpos<limit)
    {
        //testpos is guaranteed to be >= minpos and < limit
        int testpos = minpos+((limit-minpos)/2);

        if (array[testpos].equals("good")) //test index is too low
            minpos=testpos+1; //minpos always increases here  
        else
            limit=testpos; //limit always decreases here
    }

    return minpos;
}
```