# Modify binary search to find all integers in an array bigger than x and less than 2x with a time- complexity better than O(n)

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, binary-search, analysis

Let A be a sorted array containing n distinct positive integers. Let x be a positive integer such that both x and 2x are not in A.

Describe an efficient algorithm to find the number of integers in A that are larger than x and smaller than 2x

what is the complexity of the algorithm? can someone write a pseudo code without using libraries?

I know this can be done with a linear time complexity but binary search could be modify to achieve this. 
The following is the linear time complexity solution I came up with

```
def find_integers(A, x):
    integers = 0
    for element in A:
        if element > x and element < 2*x:
            integers += 1
    return integers
```

Comment: I don't think so we can achieve with the Binary Search with linear time complexity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm on a bit of a mission to improve everybody's default binary search.  As I described in this answer: [How can I simplify this working Binary Search code in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39416560/how-can-i-simplify-this-working-binary-search-code-in-c/39417165#39417165) ...

...pretty much all of my binary searches search for positions instead of elements, since it's faster and easier to get right.

It's also easily adaptable to situations like this:

```
def countBetweenXand2X(A,x):
    if x<=0:
        return 0

    # find position of first element > x

    minpos = 0
    maxpos = len(A)
    while minpos < maxpos:
        testpos = minpos + (maxpos-minpos)//2
        if A[testpos] > x:
            maxpos = testpos
        else:
            minpos = testpos+1

    start = minpos;

    # find position of first element >= 2x

    maxpos = len(A)
    while minpos < maxpos:
        testpos = minpos + (maxpos-minpos)//2
        if A[testpos] >= x*2:
            maxpos = testpos
        else:
            minpos = testpos+1

    return minpos - start
```

This is just 2 binary searches, so the complexity remains **O(log N)**.  Also note that the second search begins at the position found in the first search, since we know the second position must be `>=` the first one.  We accomplish that just by leaving `minpos` alone instead of resetting it to zero.

Answer (score 2):

As you already found out you can use binary search. Search for x and 2x and note the positions in the list, you can calculate the number of integers from the differnce between the two positions.

Since you are using python, the [bisect](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/bisect.html) module can help you with binary search.

Comment: do you have an idea how the binary search algorithm would be structured like? I need to write a pseudo code

Comment: @edogado: Just Google `binary search sorted array`. krisz's answer provides everything else you need.