# Is the following binary search code correct or incorrect? (of the book Programming Interviews Exposed)

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-search

The recursive version of the binary search in the book:

```
int binarySearch(int[] array, int target) throws BSException { return int binarySearch(int[] array, int target) throws BSException { 
    return binarySearch(array, target, 0, array.length-1);
}

int binarySearch( int[] array, int target, int lower, int upper ) throws BSException {
    int center, range;

    range = upper - lower; 

    if( range < 0 ){
        throw new BSException("Limits reversed");
    } else if( range == 0 && array[lower] != target ){ 
        throw new BSException("Element not in array");
    }

    if( array[lower] > array[upper] ){
        throw new BSException("Array not sorted"); 
    }
    center = ((range)/2) + lower; 
    if( target == array[center] ){
        return center;
    } else if( target < array[center] ){
        return binarySearch( array, target, lower, center - 1 ); 
    } 
    else {
        return binarySearch( array, target, center + 1, upper ); 
    }
}
```

and the iterative version:

```
while( true ){
    range = upper - lower;

    if( range == 0 && array[lower] != target ){
        throw new BSException("Element not in array");
    }
```

About every other algorithm book, include TAOCP by Donald Knuth, Algorithm Design Manual, Programming Pearl, etc, has "valid case" of

```
while (low <= high) {
    // ...
}
return -1;  // not found
```

or a "not found" case of `low > high`:

```
if (low > high) return -1;   // not found
```

but the recursive and iterative algorithm in the book Programming Interviews Exposed used `low > high` (meaning `range < 0`) as `BSException("Limits reversed")` and `low == high` to check for "not found". Now, if `range` is in fact less than 0, then the program would have thrown the exception of `BSException("Limits reversed")` and never be able to report NotFound.

Consider the case of an array with just 2 elements, or the `lower` and `upper` only include 2 elements, say

```
lower is 0
upper is 1
center is (1-0)/2 + 0 = 0
```

Now, let's say `target` is less than `array[center]`, then `upper = center - 1` and is `-1`, while `lower` stays as `0`. So we have `upper < lower` meaning `range < 0` but the recursive algorithm reports it as `BSException("Limits reversed")` rather than NotFound, while the iterative doesn't see `lower == upper` and go further with `upper` as `-1` and use `array[upper]` and have strange behavior?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39416560/how-can-i-simplify-this-working-binary-search-code-in-c/39417165#39417165

Comment: Your code throws "limits reversed" in a lot of "not found" cases, and has unnecessary branches.

Comment: it is code from the book. To put that into perspective: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Binary_search

Comment: You should test it.  Try `binarySearch(new int[]{0,1},-1)` and `binarySearch(new int[0],1)`.  Then get a new book.

Comment: Also:  I often ask people to write a binary search in programming interviews, so I can tell you that this line: `if( range == 0 && array[lower] != target )` means "I ran through some test cases. My search exploded. I'm not sure why, but this line fixes it".  (except it doesn't completely fix it)  If you see this in a book as something to emulate, you do really need a different book.

Comment: I was asked to write a binary search recently... I used recursion, except iterative seems simpler... and using recursion, I think I forgot to write the exit clause to begin with, and I might have written `if (low >= high) return -1;` and should have used `>` instead. But that was the 3rd question he gave me and it was about 5 minutes left for the interview. I wonder the interviewer, holding the piece of paper of standard answer, whether he would send to the hiring committee that I couldn't even write binary search correctly, and when the iterative way is so simple, why I used recursion

Comment: if it is a book and they have all the time in the world to write and to look at references, it'd be more expected that they give a good, correct solution. If it is an interviewee who hasn't written binary search for the past 10 years or 15 years, their code won't be as clean as the standard answer, which was refined again and again perhaps since 50 years ago to make it so simple and elegant. That I understand. It'd be surprising if the interviewee can come up with the cleanest solution in that 10 minute time frame

Answer (score 0):

The basic premise of binary search is keep on computing as long as `lower <= upper` is met. It means (`upper-lower`) (in your example it is `range`) can't be negative. If it is negative (`upper` is less than `lower`) you stop processing and `return -1` indicating `Not found` or throw `exception` (as in your example).

That Limits Reversed is not meaningful to the caller. So, change it to throw the exception `Not found`.

```
if (range < 0 || (range == 0 && array[lower] != target)) {
    throw new BSException("Element not in array");
}
```

However, there can be a case where the caller of this recursive function mistakenly interchanged the lower and the upper. In that case, it would say `Not found` instead of `Limits reversed` but, that's ok. Let the caller investigate and find the mistake in his code.

Comment: you said, "The basic premise of binary search is keep on computing till the time lower <= upper is met."  I thought the basic premise of binary search is keep on computing till the time lower > upper is met, or in other words, the basic premise of binary search is keep on computing as long as lower <= upper

Comment: @太極者無極而生 "The basic premise of binary search" is such a complex phrase for a grade school algorithm, specifically, "I am thinking of a number from 1 to 10" you guess, and I'll tell you higher, lower or correct. Binary Search is the process of guessing numbers amongst sorted values.

Comment: @太極者無極而生 changed the phrase. We mean the same.