# Improve speed of my binary search algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, binary-search

I have written a binary search algorithm in JavaScript:

```
function binarysearch(number, array) {
  let left = 0;
  let right = array.length - 1;
  let middle;

  while (right != left) {

    middle = Math.floor(left + (right - left) / 2);
    if (array[middle] == number) {
      return middle;
    }
    if (array[middle] < number) {
      left = array[middle];
      if (array[middle + 1] == number) {
        return middle + 1;
      }
    }
    if (array[middle] > number) {
      right = array[middle];
      if (array[middle - 1] == number) {
        return middle - 1;
      }
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

I wanted to ask if I can improve this algorithm to search faster or if some mistake is made here?

EDIT:

thank you guys for your help, this solution should work correctly now:

```
function binarysearch(number, array) {
      let left = 0;
      let right = array.length - 1;
      let middle;
      while (left <= right) {
        middle = Math.floor(left + (right - left) / 2);
        if (array[middle] == number) {
          return middle;
        }
        if (array[middle] < number) {
          left = middle + 1;
        }
        if (array[middle] > number) {
          right = middle - 1;
        }
      }
      return -1;
    }
```

Comment: If the code is working as intended this would be better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: But does it work? `left` and `right` are indices into the array, but they are assigned array values. The bounds are inclusive, so it should probably be `left = middle + 1` and `right = middle - 1`. The additional checks at `middle ± 1` are not useful and look as if they are papering over the real problem.

Comment: oh, i didnt know that a code review exist

Comment: @MOehm it works, i tested it with a sorted array of 100 million numbers, and it gives me the correct index. if it doesnt find it gives me -1 back. i tested it vs an linear search with an `for` loop and it is much faster. i compared it with `performance.now()` the time is around `0.12` vs around `102`

Comment: I'm astonished to hear that it works. The code looks broken. I've just tried to find all numbers from 0 to 20 in the array `[3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 12, 14, 16]` and I get an infinite loop. What does your test look like? A million consecutive numbers, starting at 1? That _could_ work, given that you mix up array values and indices and would explain the spurious `+ 1` strewn about.

Comment: i see got an infinity loop too. i just made an `for` loop, and for each loop iteration it pushes its iteration into the array `array.push(i)` up to 100 million , and then i search an number.

Comment: That's a very special case. You were only interested in making it big, but you need to test some edge cases, too: Search on an empty array (in which case your `right` is −1, ouch!), search for elements outside the range of the array, an array with gaps, an array with duplicated elements, ... Linear search is slow, but it's faster than an infinite loop. `:)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39416560/how-can-i-simplify-this-working-binary-search-code-in-c/39417165#39417165

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are taking values as indices. If you take greater values than indices, you see your codes does not work.

Instead, you could take the index of `middle` for `left` or `right`if not found.

```js
function binarysearch(number, array) {
    let left = 0,
        right = array.length - 1,
        middle;

    while (left <= right) {
        middle = Math.floor((left + right) / 2);
        if (array[middle] === number) return middle;
        if (array[middle] > number) right = middle - 1;
        else left = middle + 1;
    }
    return -1;
}

console.log(binarysearch(0, [43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50]));
console.log(binarysearch(43, [43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50]));
console.log(binarysearch(44, [43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50]));
console.log(binarysearch(45, [43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50]));
console.log(binarysearch(46, [43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50]));
console.log(binarysearch(47, [43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50]));
console.log(binarysearch(48, [43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50]));
console.log(binarysearch(49, [43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50]));
console.log(binarysearch(50, [43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50]));
console.log(binarysearch(100, [43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score -1):

Make it easier

```
  let left = 0;
  let right = array.length - 1;
  let middle;

  while (right != left) {

    middle = Math.floor(left + (right - left) / 2);
    if (array[middle] == number) {
      return middle;
    }
    if (array[middle] < number) {
      left = array[middle] + 1;
    }
    if (array[middle] > number) {
      right = array[middle];
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's easier. Unfortunately, this function suffers from the same problems as OP's code: It mixes up array indices and values. It should be `left = middle + 1`, for example. You should also make up your mind whether you want to use inclusive upper bounds, in which case it's `right = middle - 1` or exclusive upper bounds, in which case it's just `right = array.length`. Given that Javascript uses exclusive upper bounds for arrays, I'd prefer the latter.