# Binary Search detail

Tags: python, algorithm, computer-science

I am new to python and trying to learn some algorithm techniques.

can someone please help me understand what it is that I am doing wrong here? I am getting an error with

> IndexError: list index out of range

this is my code

```
def binary_search(arr,item):
    #keeping track of elements in array
    low = 0
    high = len(arr)
    #mid section 
    while low <= high:
        mid = (low + high)
        guess = arr[mid]
        if guess == item:
            return mid
        if guess > item:
            high = mid - 1
        else:
            low = mid + 1
    return None

a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]

print(binary_search(a, 3))
```

Comment: You typically find the midpoint by dividing in half with `mid = (low + high) // 2`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39416560/how-can-i-simplify-this-working-binary-search-code-in-c/39417165#39417165

Comment: Ah, I can't believe I missed that. Those are the new errors I am not used to catching. Thank you for that.

Comment: Also, start `high = len(arr)-1`. If you search for 21 then it will throw an error.

Comment: I appreacite the assistance, as I was following a Algorithm Book it has a typo in there. Grokking Algorithms is the name .