# The terminating point of binarysearch

Tags: c++, algorithm

why is the terminating condition of the binary search is activated when (low>high), i have searched on the internet and everyone say that it indicates that the array is empty, but i think the array is empty when low is equal to high, N.B: low is the starting index and high is the ending index.

Comment: Depends on whether the [range is open or closed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Notations_for_intervals).

Comment: In C++ using iterator conventions low(begin) == high(end) means empty.  But it's easy to make it work the other way too, you just have to be consistent everywhere.  Getting this wrong is a quick way to have bugs, including infinite loops or plain wrong answers.

Comment: I find it really annoying when people write a binary search like that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39416560/how-can-i-simplify-this-working-binary-search-code-in-c/39417165#39417165

Comment: @MattTimmermans I've always found it easier to write a binary search with low and high both being inside the search range.  I imagine it's a personal preference.

Comment: For an interesting take on the difficulty of writing a binary search, see https://reprog.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/are-you-one-of-the-10-percent/

Answer (score 0):

you are not wrong. the array is empty when low is equal to high. but for this condition (low>high) to be true, low would first have to be equal to high. So the two statements are both correct in a way

Answer (score 0):

It depends on meaning of `high`. If `high` is last index (not a length of interval) then condition should be `(low<=high)`.
My choice is to use "last index" because when you calculate `mid` you refer by `high` as `array[high]`.