# Binary Search Index Questions

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search

When performing a binary search on answer, I've seen different forms of the following:

`loop condition : (low+1<hi), (low<hi), (low<=hi) updating indices: (hi=mid+1), (hi=mid), (low=mid), (low=mid-1)`

What is the difference between these and do they actually matter?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39416560/how-can-i-simplify-this-working-binary-search-code-in-c/39417165#39417165

Answer (score 1):

Each of the loop conditions simply state when the loop will end. If you want to find exactly one element `lo < hi` is usually the easiest method. For two elements, or `lo + 1 < hi` could be used. `lo <= hi` is usually paired with an early return statement in the while loop.

Before updating the indices, a `mid` is chosen usually either `(lo + hi) / 2` or `(lo + hi + 1) / 2` (ignoring integer overflow). The difference between these is that the first has a bias towards `lo` if there are an even number of elements between `lo` and `hi`, whereas the second has a bias towards `hi`.

The updating indices have `+ 1` attached to them to ensure that there is no infinite loop. In general, you want to make sure `lo` and `hi` are modified by at least 1 for every iteration of the loop.

For reference, here is my preferred way of doing binary search:

```cpp
int binary_search(std::vector<int> nums, int target) {
    if (nums.empty())
        return -1;

    int l = 0;
    int h = nums.size() - 1;
    while (l < h) {
        // If the language doesn't have big ints, make sure there is no overflow. 
        // This has a left bias if there are an even number of elements left.
        int m = l + (h - l) / 2;

        if (nums[m] < target) {
            // The `+ 1` here is important. Without this, if there are two elements 
            // and nums[0] < target, we'll get an infinite loop.
            l = m + 1; 
        } else {
            // Since `m < h`, we "make progress" in this case.
            h = m;
        }
    }

    return nums[l] == target ? l : -1;
}
```

I like this method, because it is clear that there is no infinite loop, and the exit condition does not rely on early return statements.