# Infinite loop in binary search algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, binary-search

I'm a newbie in algorithms. I have recently started studying binary search and tryed to implement it on my own. The task is simple: we have an array of integers `a` and an integer `x`. If `a` contains `x` the result should be its index, otherwise the function should return `-1`.

Here is the code I have written:

```
def binary_search(a, x):
    l = 0
    r = len(a)
    while r - l > 0:
        m = (l + r) // 2
        if a[m] < x:
            l = m
        else:
            r = m
    if a[l] == x:
        return l
    return -1
```

But this code stucks in infinite cycle on `a = [1, 2]` and `x = 2`. I suppose, that I have incorrect cycle condition (probably, should be `r - l >= 0`), but this solution does not help. Where am I wrong?

Comment: look at the case r = 0 and l = 0

Comment: you are not considering case in loop if `a[m]==x`

Comment: `if a[m] < x: m = l+1`  Also make sure `l < len(a)`  at the end.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39416560/how-can-i-simplify-this-working-binary-search-code-in-c/39417165#39417165

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me do some desk checking. I'll assume `a = [1, 2]` and we are searching for a 2

So we start with

```
l = 0
r = 2
```

Since `r - l = 2 > 0`, we enter the while-loop.

```
m = (l + r) / 2 = (0 + 2) / 2 = 1
a[m] = a[1] = 2 == x  (hence not less than x)
r = m = 1 (and l remains the same)
```

Now `r - l = 1 - 0 = 1 > 0`, so we continue

```
m = (l + r) / 2 = (0 + 1) / 2 = 0
a[m] = a[0] = 1 < x
l = m = 0 (and r remains the same)
```

After this iteration both `r` and `l` have the same value as before, which then produces an endless loop.

Ashok's answer is a great fix. But I think it'll be educational to do some desk checking on the fixed code and look what improves it.

Basically the problematic situation arises, when `l + 1 = r`.
Then `m` will always evaluate to `l`, `a[l] < x` and `l` is set to `m` again, which doesn't change the situation.

In a larger piece of code it'll make sense to make a table that contains a column for each variable to watch and a column to write down the code line that was evaluated. A column for remarks won't harm either.

Answer (score 0):

As Mani mentioned you are not considering when `A[m]==x`. Include that case (at that point you've found `a` so just return `m`), and once you have that case we can let `l=m+1` when we are still below x. Like this:

```
def binary_search(a, x):
    l = 0
    r = len(a)
    while r - l > 0:
        m = (l + r) // 2
        if a[m] < x:
            l = m + 1
        elif a[m]==x:
            return m
        else:
            r = m
    if l<len(a) and a[l] == x:
        return l
    return -1
```